# How to pass token for AES encrypted video for AdaptiveMediaSource UWP

Tags: uwp, azure-media-services

I'm doing a UWP application, I have some videos encrypted with AES and I use Media Azure Service to store them and Azure Active Directory to get a Oauth Token when I do the smooth streaming.

From what I understood in this post : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2015/07/31/uwp-new-controls-part-5-media.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage

Know you don't need to use the Smooth Streaming SDK to play Smooth Streaming Video.

If I play a none encrypted video with the AdaptiveMediaSource I have no problem but if I want to play one encrypted with AES how can I do this ?

I need to pass the OAuth token and the issuer of the token.

I saw the AdaptiveMediaSource have a constructor that you can pass an HttpClient but the doc is quite lacking.

Anybody have an idea how it's possible ?

Thanks

Comment: Here has the official [doc](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/learning-paths/media-services-streaming-live/) about Encode live stream with AMS. But do you want to encrypt and decrypt the stream all in your app?

Comment: I use dynamic encryption in Media Azure Service and it's encrypted with AES and to play the stream I use Smooth Streaming.  Seems this crash in UWP

Comment: Found a official doc for you: [Using AES-128 Dynamic Encryption and Key Delivery Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-protect-with-aes128/), sorry I'm not familiar with Media Azure Service, wish this can help you.